# Pass props from function? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

EDIT:

I've edited the question, to make it more clear:

So normally you can pass down props inside the render() function, like so:

```
render(){

 return(
  <div>
   <ExampleStatelessComponent message={this.state.message}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Then, message can be used with props inside the component via props.message.

Can this be done inside a function as well? For example, what if i don't want to render ExampleStatelessComponent, but pass props to it? Could i use a function, for example componentDidMount to pass props to a stateless component?

```
componentDidMount(){

 <ExampleStatelessComponent message={this.state.message}

}
```

is this possible? Hope this clarify things up. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: Are you intending to render a component called `ExampleStateless` in response to a click or simply to update the `Placeholder`? In short, yes, this is possible, but not sure what you are trying to do to give good response

Comment: Normally you pass down props inside the render function. The question is if this can be achieved without using render, so in this case, after a function gets triggered, pass down props to a specific component but without the render function.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: why would you want to update props when you don't want to render that component, Doesn't it become a normal function then??

Comment: For example, if you have a fileuploader component that triggers functions once the upload starts. If you import the fileuploader to another component in your app, you will be able to upload files, but the component that renders fileuploader has no access to the functions or state of the fileuploader. Sure, you could connect the fileuploader to redux and then share for example the filename via redux, but i wanted to know if i could do that without redux by just using props.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to pass down and render a stateless function, but you are not using your stateless function inside the render function of the parent component, as you are calling it `onClick`.

Additionally you are not returning anything from your statelss function.

A valid example would be:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    hello: 'HelloWorld',
    isChildVisible: false,
  }

  onClickFunction = () => {
    this.setState({isChildVisible: true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 onClick={this.onClickFunction}> Placeholder </h3>
        {
          this.state.isChildVisible &&
          <ExampleStateless message={this.state.message} />
        }
      </div >
    );
  }
}

const ExampleStateless = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.message}</div>
  );
}
```

More info on stateless functions is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)